# I can't get solarized plugin to work in vim (I am using vim-plug)

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, plugin-solarized

I just started using vim. As I understand it, using  a plugin manager is the easiest way of installing plugins for vim. So I thought I would try vim-plug which I installed using curl as explained [here](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug). Then I looked for plugins on [vimawesome](https://vimawesome.com/) and I thought I would try to install [solarized colors](https://vimawesome.com/plugin/vim-colors-solarized-ours). I just put this in my .vimrc

```
call plug#begin()
Plug 'altercation/vim-colors-solarized'
call plug#end()
```

then I opened vim and did PlugInstall and PlugUpdate but when I open a new vim I don't get the solarized colors. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**

I tried the suggestion but when I type `:colorscheme solarized` I get the following 
[image]

Comment: fancy colorschemes use colors unavailable for terminals, unless you prepare it by providing color palette or if terminal supports termguicolors option. Thus, first of all try `:set termguicolors` and then `:colo solarized`.

Comment: And if you go to the URL you show us there is a BIG section `IMPORTANT NOTE FOR TERMINAL USERS:` you should read.

Answer (score 2):

You need to load it. Add `colorscheme solarized` to your `.vimrc`. You can also load it on the fly executing `:colorscheme solarized` on the Vim command line

Comment: When I try the suggestion I get something as I printed above which doesn't seem right

Comment: @roi_saumon you need to enable `termguicolors` with `set termguicolors` and use a terminal emulator that supports them. I think on Linux most terminal emulators do, on macOS you can try iTerm2 or (my favourite) Kitty

Comment: Alacritty also @Tae. But it's not completely necessary if you happen to like Terminal.app or `tmux`, and you set up your term's color palette correctly.